# Python Pillow Image.load() method has limitations?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to do some image processing in python.

I'm using Pillow 8.4.0 for this purpose and I need to work on individual pixels (here I'm just trying to save pixels in a text file), therefore I'm trying to use **Image.load()** method and looping over it but it is throwing **IndexError: image index out of range**

Is there a limitation in **Image.load()** function that is preventing me to do this?

```
from PIL import Image

with Image.open('nature.jpg') as img:
    print("Image size is : " ,img.size)
    
    pixels = img.load()
    
    with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
        
        for row in range(img.height):
            for col in range(img.width):
                
                file.write(str(pixels[row, col])+ ' ')
                
            file.write('\n')
```

Output is:

```
Image size is :  (1024, 768)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    file.write(str(pixels[row, col])+ ' ')
IndexError: image index out of range
```

Comment: Try `pixels[col,row]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pillow` expects (x,y) rather than (y,x). Please try following:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('nature.jpg')
pixels = img.load()
print(pixels[img.width-1,img.height-1])  # does provide tuple describing pixel
print(pixels[img.height-1,img.width-1])  # IndexError for non-square image
```